# Using generics as method arguments in discriminated unions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Let’s say we have a discriminated union which accepts an argument of itself:

```
type TextInput<Props extends Inputs<Props>> = {
    type: 'text',
    value?: string,
    options?: undefined
}

type CheckboxInput<Props extends Inputs<Props>> = {
    type: 'checkbox',
    options: string[] | number[],
    value?: Props['options'] extends Array<infer T> ? T : never
}

type Events<Props extends Inputs<Props>> = { onInput?: (arg: Inputs<Props>['value']) => any }

type Inputs<Props extends Inputs<Props>> = TextInput<Props> | CheckboxInput<Props>
```

This works, and we can do some pretty remarkable things:

```
type Make = <P extends Inputs<P>>(props: P) => {}

declare const create: Make

create({ type: 'text', value: '123' })  // 
create({ type: 'text', value: 123 }) //  (value must be a string)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
create({ type: 'checkbox', options: ['a', 'b'], value: 'a' }) // 
create({ type: 'checkbox', options: [1, 2, 3], value: 2 }) // 
create({ type: 'checkbox', options: ['a', 'b'], value: 2 }) //  (value must match options type)
                                                ^^^^^^^^
```

However, I’d like to add a method to the discriminated union, and ensure that the argument of that method also matches the value type. This does not appear to be possible:

```
type TextInput<Props extends Inputs<Props>> = {
    type: 'text',
    value?: string,
    options?: undefined
} & Events<Props>

type CheckboxInput<Props extends Inputs<Props>> = {
    type: 'checkbox',
    options: string[] | number[],
    value?: Props['options'] extends Array<infer T> ? T : never
} & Events<Props>

type Events<Props extends Inputs<Props>> = { onInput?: (arg: Inputs<Props>['value']) => any }

type Inputs<Props extends Inputs<Props>> = TextInput<Props> | CheckboxInput<Props>

type Make = <P extends Inputs<P>>(props: P) => {}

declare const create: Make

create({ type: 'checkbox', options: [1, 2, 3], value: 1, onInput: (arg) => arg }) //  "arg" in onInput should only be a number, matching the value type
```

**Question: Is there any way to use the narrowed union data as the argument of a method inside the union?**

[Full TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhAewCSA7MBXYAeACgJwHswBnKBYCFAE1NQ2GN0JID4WoBeKAbwFgAoKEKihIALigByCokkAaAcKgA3AIYAbdBAD8E4sDwBLFAHMFg4UWCGCKYrqjpqEAGbGIVAQF8oAMigAosqUDExExCwCAqLQAMIAFhAAxgDWAEYE8HSYYSRkiJQ0UNmh+OFsnDyKwjESkkmJqRnw8tVCVjZ2egbGJgDaALpQAD5QKOgAtmkQeIPmSmqaOhJlJH2SHbbEkkPkhaQAgnh4qiBYxi4zsOzasFASKBDBeN5+gcEopcwRUfwx7yFGKtSHtqLQ0Jggd8KlxuFBbCUHAAKVR4EwSEpQ8rrRZaHYASk47FUKBAUC8v3+mNyIIKYOKEK+5XYXDgiBKNPYowSyXSmQ5wMi-Gi4GgAFlVCloFxcPkKPTqTg2EiwN8VoSOOxuBThbqBFRkupUdAkltgFAkngIKoKBIJVLfpbrRQkXDalIZMB5CoNFo6gBGABMAGZJOTCVAAPSRqCAXg3ALI7AidNogrpEorqnu9uIgEiDwfDUZjCagSJzUAm6H0UGmUFUUH0RlM+N+SatKbT7vqjT5LTk8LA1i2EnWqm9kjS46SO37ObqY8L0bjif4yZdbozUgavOa3s2XSgfX9-cD-eDA1nvtzUEDi+LK7XqY34i3Pd3-f3xBHkjH-YnU5nH0lgkW8vEJJcSzLK8Kyrc0JhtBoByHOx00gFs9VXdt11Q69ux3TI90HTov0PY8bzPC8gL9KAyIRRkJBRNENWJNE7zjQA5HagAAiVETC4qBjHhFASgbeICHQdQqCE9QyVretximGZ+3g4AGl6EREio6AYlbfggA)

Comment: I feel like this might ultimately be [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) and might be fixable somehow, but right now I'm just trying to wrap my head around your code.  Is there some particular reason (other than the lack of callback param inference) that you're not using [something specific like this](https://tsplay.dev/wO1zRm) instead of recursive generics?  I think it's the same basic situation but my brain leaks out of my ears less.

Comment: Fair question @jcalz — to be clear my brain is leaking out my ears too — the full context is in this [wip branch of FormKit](https://github.com/formkit/formkit/blob/feature/strict-types/packages/inputs/src/props.ts) — but essentially — there are a number of places where that value type must be inferred from the end user. For example the options in my contrived example also allow `Array<{ label: string, value: unknown }>`. Overall the recursive generics work great, and the only place I’ve encountered this issue is arguments of methods. They even work as return values of methods.

Comment: Hmm, well I'm not likely to wade into an even larger example to figure out what's going on. So does that mean any fix that doesn't use recursive generics is a non-starter for you?  Like, it looks like your code can be simplified way down to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK37pW) maybe, which works, but I don't know if you'd be likely to accept an answer like that.  What do you think?

Comment: I would love to not need recursive generics — but my current working assumption is it is necessary since the `value` type is often derived from the Props generic. At least as it pertains to this specific question I believe [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) is the correct answer — will mark as such too if submitted.